# Mipmaps in gles2 coming out blank

Tags: c, opengl-es-2.0

```
glGenTextures(1, &bigTex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, bigTex);
u32 mipmapLevel = max(0, (int)greaterOrEqualPowerOfTwoExponent(max(packing.bounds.x, packing.bounds.y)) - 4);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mipmapLevel, GL_ALPHA, texSpan.x, texSpan.y, 0, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, dat);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

This seems to be producing blank (and opaque) textures. Disabling mipmaps by setting mipmapLevel to zero causes it to render as normal, but of course, then there is no mipmapping.

Answer (score 0):

the mipmap level argument of glImage2d doesn't mean what you think it means. It specifies the mipmap level of dat, not the desired lowest mipmap level associated with bigTex, so what you're saying there is that you want to define the fifth mipmap level of bigTex. You never see the fifth mipmap level of bigTex, so everything just looks blank- because you never defined the higher mipmap levels.

Since dat is the most detailed level (`0`), that's the level you define. So get rid of `mipmapLevel`, and do

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA, texSpan.x, texSpan.y, 0, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, dat);
```

You've seen that this works, but you think it's disabling mipmapping because the results of downscaling don't look good. Mipmaps should be in effect, at that point. Set your GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER to GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST instead of GL_LINEAR, and throw in a `glHint(GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP_HINT, GL_NICEST);` for good measure, and you will see that.